# Setting up wifi with AT&T mobile data plan?

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm planning on getting an AT&T unlimited data plan for my phone with my grandparents on the plan. My grandparents don't have high speed wi-fi atm and I would like to get them connected using tablets and other devices that don't have sim card support like the Amazon echo show.

Is this possible? How can I do this?

Comment: Are you saying you want to get AT&T broadband installed at your grandparents' home and link the billing to your AT&T wireless account? Or are you saying you want them to have access to "attwifi" public hotspots at Starbucks or whatever?

Comment: AT&T Unlimited plan Terms & Conditions don't allow for tethering, plus it is limited to 3Mbps, not very effective even if you tempt getting booted by bypassing the restriction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, this is easy. It is a violation of AT&T's terms and conditions. I do not know how strongly enforced this is, but technically it's easy enough if they ever decide to enforce it. The likelihood probably depends greatly on how much data they use and how often.

If you're determined, what you need is an unlocked, unbranded LTE to Wi-Fi router (or USB modem + USB router) that supports LTE bands 2, 4, 5, 12 and 17 (technically only 12 or 17 is needed, 17 is a subset of 12 that excludes some channels AT&T doesn't own - also you can do without 2 and 5 realistically, but to be the most future proof it'd be best to have them). Again, though, it's probably best avoided.